# mysqldump causes mysqld to spin forever

Tags: mysql

I'm doing a --where query in my mysqldump with an IN clause, yet when I do the same query in mysql client it instantly spits out 5 numbers.

Here is my query:
mysqldump qid qids --single-transaction --where="id in (select qid_id from qids join groups_qids on qids.id=groups_qids.qid_id where groups_qids.group_id=412)"

And when I noticed it was taking seconds, I realized something was wrong, soon my site was non-responsive, and top showed that mysqld was taking 90+% of the CPU cycles.  I saw nothing in /var/log/mysqld.log of interest, and eventually did a "sudo service mysqld restart" to get back to normal.  This repeatedly happens, its not a one time thing.

Is there a way to actually do this?

My goal is to export a handful of rows from a table -- those rows are the ones whose ID matches the sub-query.  I want to pull those into a development database server.

Comment: I would rather create a view from the query and export the view's content.

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do in your mysqldump? Is it something that could be done with a script?

Comment: @Shadow that doesn't really make sense, I'm just doing a quick little hack job to take some data (like 5 rows in this case) out of the table and to pull it into my dev database.  To pull out 5 rows, this shouldn't crash MySQL.  I'm using version 5.5 btw.

Comment: @dan08 I added the last line "My goal is to export a handful of rows from a table -- those rows are the ones whose ID matches the sub-query. I want to pull those into a development database server." -- but why would I do this with a script?  I want to pull out 5 (in this case) rows from the database?  

I ended up just doing 5 separate mysqldump calls with --where="id=[one of the 5 ids]" but this felt very unsatisfying and like I'm missing something with my MySQL skills...